# Including external JavaScript libraries in new react app which is configured using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am new to react.js. I downloaded a theme which have external JavaScript libraries i.e bootstrap.min.js , jquery.min.js, slider.js, jquery-flexslider.min.js.

I created a React app using create-react-app and I copied all the external JavaScript libraries and CSS files in `index.html` of the public folder of my react app and copied all the html of `index.html` of my theme in `app.js` which I downloaded. All the CSS are working fine but the JavaScript libraries are not working on the page.

Following is the demo of how I included the css files and javascript libraries in `index.html` of the public folder.

```
<script src="/assets/javascript/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/assets/javascript/jquery.easing.js"></script>    
<script src="/assets/javascript/jquery-waypoints.js"></script>
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/responsive.css"/>`
```

Now my question is, how should I include the JavaScript libraries so that it start working. I tried to put all the files in the src folder of my react app but it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [`react-bootstrap`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io) instead of `jquery` and a minified bootstrap file. By using `react-bootstrap` you get bootstrap 3 (4 is in the works) as nicely designed react components that you can selectively import and use.  So then you can

```
import React from 'react'
import{ string } from 'prop-types'
import { Col, Row, Label } from 'react-bootstrap'

const PrettyThing = ({ thing }) => (
  <Row>
    <Col xs={9} xsOffset={1}>
      <Label bsStyle="success">{thing}</Label>
    </Col>
  </Row>
)

PrettyThing.propTypes = { thing: string.isRequired }

export default PrettyThing
```

and `webpack` will handle how that's all sliced and diced so only the css you need gets built.

see https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/ for more info.